# return and add a new line without executing the current command in bash?

Tags: bash, command

After I had typed a long command in the bash, i determined not to execute it for some reason.
But i just wanted to start a new line without clear the command. That command was still on the screen? Somebody help me?

```
#I typed as below:
$>find -name "filepattern" -exec grep "hello" {} \;

#I wanted as below without executing the 'find' command.
$>find -name "filepattern" -exec grep "hello" {} \;
$>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> to 'cancel' a command you've typed.

My testing, on OS X:

```
bash-3.2$ find -name "filepattern" -exec grep "hello" {} \; <ctrl+c>
bash-3.2$ 

bash-3.2$ /bin/bash -version
/bin/bash -version
GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin12)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
bash-3.2$
```

Comment: @cebewee It doesn't in `bash 3.2` on OS X. What version are you using?

Comment: @simont bash 4.2.36 for me. To clarify. With "clear" I mean that the line I typed and canceled with ctrl-c is not executed and also not entered into the history, so I cannot easily recover it afterwards. It is still displayed in the terminal, though.

Answer (score 6):

A useful bash shortcut is <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>#</kbd> to comment out the current command.

For example:

```
$ find -name "filepattern" -exec grep "hello" {} \; <Alt+#>
$ #find -name "filepattern" -exec grep "hello" {} \; 
$
```

I like this because it stores the command in your history. You can then go back to it, remove the `#` and run it. With `Ctrl+C` you lose the command you have written.

Comment: Alt-# does nothing on my version of Bash, Ctrl-# however does the thing you describe (although unreliably, wonder what causes that)

Comment: Run `bind -P | grep insert-comment` to see what your binding is. Mine is `\M-#` and the meta key is `Alt` on a PC.

Comment: Good to know. Its"\e#" for me. This is also mapped to Alt-# (or ESC-#) on my machine. There is a conflict my keyboard layout, so this issue is solved. I could rebind this key with the `bind` command.

Comment: What is 'bind'? I don't have the command. I'm using arch linux.

Comment: @kinolucky "bind" is a bash built-in to "[d]isplay current readline key and function bindings, bind a key sequence to a readline function or macro, or set a readline variable." See "man bash" for details. It's possible you're using a different shell (such as tcsh, ksh, or zsh)

Answer (score 2):

One ad-hoc solution is to add a '#' add the beginning of the current line to turn it into a comment.

Comment: Very intereting and it's useful.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> gives you a new line to start with.
You can continue with the old command which you were typing earlier using <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>